Solution to IMO 2020 P2?
I'm asking to see if my proof of the IMO 2020 P2 is valid. It doesn't follow the typical solution provided so I just wanted to ask if it's correct. The question asks to prove that for all $a, b, c, d$ where $a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d\geqslant 0$, and $a+b+c+d=1$, that $(a+2b+3c+4d)(a^ab^bc^cd^d)$ is less than $1$.
Here's my proof: $a+2b+3c+4d\leqslant a+b+c+d+a+b+c+d+2d=2+2d$. Since $2d$ is at most $2\times 0.25$, $a+2b+3c+4d)\leqslant 2+0.5=2.5$. Now $a^ab^bc^cd^d\leqslant (abcd)^d$ since a smaller exponent would increase a number between $0$ and $1$. Also note that, $a^ab^bc^cd^d\leqslant a^{a+b+c+d}=a$. Now, this is exactly equal when $a=d$ or $d=0.25$. So now we can consider $(abcd)^d$ with $d=0.25$ because that is when it is largest as per the previous inequality. By the AM-GM inequality, $(abcd)^{0.25}\leqslant\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}=0.25$. Finally $2.5\times 0.25=0.625$ so it's less than one.
The specific part that I would like verification on is whether my deduction that the expression,$(a+2b+3c+4d)(a^ab^bc^cd^d)$,is at a maximum when $d=0.25$ is correct.

So your question : "is my answer valid ?". An advise : enclose your formulas with dollar signs, like this  : $(a+b)$(this work has been well done by @Tuvasbien (moi aussi...)

@JeanMarie yes that's my question

Your proof attempt as is, is not valid. Take for example say $b=c=d = 10^{-10}$ and $a= 1-(3 \times 10^{-10})$. Then you can check by taking natural logs that $b^bc^cd^d = 10^{(-10) \times (3  \times 10^{-10})} = e^{-30 \ln(10) \times 10^{-10}}$ [$= e^{-\epsilon}$ for some quite small $\epsilon >0$], is actually quite close to $1$. [This remains much larger than your claimed upper bound of $.625$ and in fact still quite close to $1$ even after multiplying by $a^a \approx 1$ and $a^a \ge a$. Note, finally, that you have to multiply this by $a+2b+3c+4d$, which is in fact larger than $1$.
I trust from the wording of your OP that you have seen the accepted solution to this question.

Thanks for pointing that out. I noticed I made a mistake in saying $(a+2b+3c+4d)=(2+2d)$ when it should be $(2+c+2d)$ which is less than $3$. But even with this mistake corrected, the math doesn't work out. Do you know which specific step I went wrong? I suspect it's in the way I treated the inequalities but I don't see what step was wrong.

Your big mistake is in assuming that $(a+2b+3c+4d)(a^ab^bc^cd^d)$ is maximized [restricted to the given domain that is] at $a=b=c=d=.25$.

I'm understanding where I went wrong better, and I'll put this in case someone finds this helpful. Trivially, I missed that $(a+2b+3c+4d)$ is actually $(2+c+2d)$. But more importantly, my deduction that $(a^ab^bc^cd^d)$ is at a maximum when $d=0.25$ is incorrect. Though the inequality $a^ab^bc^cd^d\leqslant a^{a+b+c+d}=a$ is only equal when $d=0.25$ it doesn't imply a maximum because $a$ is not a constant. Even if making $d$ smaller means that $a^ab^bc^cd^d<a^{a+b+c+d}=a$, the increase in the bound, as determined by $a$, may mean that $(a^ab^bc^cd^d)$ for this larger $a$-value, though smaller than $a$, is larger than $a^ab^bc^cd^d$ when $d=0.25$.
